# How to break a condition statement and go to elif/else once reached inside the condition block?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an `if`/`elif`/`else` block in my code, however, I figured out that there is a time my code goes through the `elif` statement but by the end of the `elif` block I realized that my inputs are not being applied to the code inside. So that means I needed to check the next `elif`/`else`. Is there a way I can break the current "condition" block and consider it as if it was not visited?

I won't be able to share my code but I can try to give you an example:

```py
group = [A, B, C]

if condition:
   pass
elif len(group) >= 3:
    for each in group:
        if not processed(each):
            process(each)
else:
    # do something else
```

There is a lot going through the `if` block, but there is a time everything in the group is processed, and I would like to still visit the `else` block if that happens as if I never went through the `elif` block.

Comment: `Is there a way I can break the current "condition" block and consider it as if it was not visited` No.

Comment: well there is this http://entrian.com/goto/

Comment: Sounds like you want to call a function recursively while having some control variables outside the scope of this funciton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `else` to an `if` and use a boolean. It is a bit hackish though...

```
do_else_block = True
if condition:
    do_else_block = False
    pass
elif len(group) >= 3:
    for each in group:
        if not processed(each):
            do_else_block = False
            process(each)
if do_else_block:
    # do something else
```

Answer (score -1):

Not all of your code needs to be in an `if` or `else` block.  If you want something to happen regardless of the `if` condition, just unindent it.

```
group = [A,B,C]

if not condition and len(group) >=3:  # combine the two checks into one "if"
    for each in group:
        if not processed(each):
            process(each)

do something else  # this happens regardless because it's not in an "else"
```

Going off the interpretation in Solomon's answer, I'd express that same logic as:

```
if len(group) >= 3 and not condition:
    to_process = [e for e in group if not processed(e)]
else:
    to_process = []
for each in to_process:
    process(each)
if not condition and not to_process:
    # do something else
```

Comment: I still need `else` statement and the combination you suggested might still go through but do not process any of the elements in the group. That is why I want to visit else conditions. 
So is it possible to visit a condition and then visit `elif`/`else` for some reason?

Comment: Just remove the `if`, then?  You're not really explaining what you want to happen under what conditions -- if you want everything to happen no matter what, don't use an `if` block at all.

Comment: @Samwise I agree that the question is really hard to read but the last paragraph (and Solomon's answer) explains the desired behavior: if the `if not processed()` is true for *every* item in `group`, the code block in the `else` should happen. If the `condition` is true or if not all the elements in `group` get processed then it shouldn't.